# maximum enum usage in schema

Tags: mysql, enums

i need to populate a table column which takes **one of 30 different string values**. Is it advisable to use enum here for speed up processing . Can anyone suggest better solution which is *reasonably optimum for storage and processing*(comparison)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are most probably better of by putting the string values in a different table and joining them into your table by (`TINYINT`) id. it is a [much cleaner and more maintainable approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362044/mysql-enum-type-vs-join-tables/362058#362058), and the performance difference (with proper setup and indexing) [is neglectable](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/).