# Using 1 digit codes VS descriptive strings for ENUMs in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, enums

In my `user_accounts` table, I have a field called `source` which is an `ENUM`. It indicates how the user was referred to the website. Possible values are via Facebook, via Email, or via regular website signup.

There are 3 possible options for how I can store these values in the database:

- As a full string, i.e `facebook, email , website`
- As a 1 letter code, e.g `F, E, W`
- As a 1 number code, e.g `1, 2, 3`

Which approach is the best approach from a database performance / maintainence point of view? Is there going to be any impact (such as faster queries) if I stored the values as 1 letter / digit codes rather than as the full strings? This column will be used in `WHERE` statements.

Comment: Educated guess: string will be slower to compare than number, but slightly.

Comment: As for the third option: beware! `INSERT INTO ... (myEnumField) VALUES ('1')` is *not* equal to `INSERT INTO ... (myEnumField) VALUES (1)` (first is `ENUM` value, second is index)! My suggestion: avoid this by using strings (the readable ones, I prefer). Also, see [MySQL Enum performance advantage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766299/mysql-enum-performance-advantage) for good insight on `ENUM`s in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise, ENUMS really tend to the most optimized (As the system knows the possible set of values, it uses different algos in searching etc etc). You can store the full string with ENUMS ('FACEBOOK', etc etc) and they will take only 1 byte of space per row! (provided its less than 256 enums in total).  However, use enums only if you know for sure that F,E,W are the only options you will see. Adding new ENUMS is a pain as you will have to alter the table to update the enum values, and you will have to ensure the enum order.

A close second is digits. The issue with that is readability. You may end up having to keep another table to understand what each digit stands for. (Either in the database or in the application)

Varchar is the worst when it comes to speed of query, but is the most readable and managable.

Comment: Is there any improvement if using a single letter, e.g `F` instead of `Facebook`?

Comment: I havent exactly tested single letters, but they would be slower than int by a very low margin. I can say it wins as an average of performance (a close third) and readability. However, use CHAR(1) instead of VARCHAR(1), I believe varchar adds another byte to just know the length of the string (its varchar(256) or less).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you use numbers, you might save a few CPU cycles. Which equals about how long it takes one of the neurons in your brain to talk to another. In layman's terms, unless you plan on doing it several billion times a second, it's better to go with which option is most readable and flexible, saving you many seconds on debugging effort, which is most likely longer than the saving you'll get by using numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are going to use this field in a WHERE clause, you are better off using the numeric enumerator.  It is generally true that you should index fields that will be filtered or sorted on (I say generally because you really need to verify with query execution plans whether the index is worth the overhead).

With this being said, however, an ENUM is a mess to use.  If you decide down the road to change something, it is difficult to change.  Also, if you pass in bad data, unless you have SQL strict on you will just end up with a NULL in that field.  You also cannot add other attributes to the ENUM data such as whether it is active or legacy, etc.  Finally, it is much more difficult to use the ENUM information in your applications directly (such as populating a drop-down menu with your ENUM choices).

Here is a good SO question about this topic:

[MySQL ENUM type vs join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362044/mysql-enum-type-vs-join-tables)

In the end, I would recommend that you use a joined table and a PK/FK relationship.  If you want a faster query, just don't link the table in and use the index as your numeric enumerator.  This fits much better into a good database design compared to using an ENUM in my opinion.

Comment: +1 - the maintenance issues around Enums are significant, and in terms of performance, you're unlikely to see an improvement versus having an integer column as a foreign key to a "sources" table.