# Enum vs Lookup Table for Large Dataset and Few Fields Option

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i am badly stuck in a database design problem and need recommendation from you guys.
I have lot of fields which have only few value (between 1 to 10)and most of them are unchangeable like YES, No or Option 1, Option 2, Option 3

I have 3 choices to implement a design in database

1. I should insert values as a string ( Which i consider not a good thing for large scale data).
2. I should create enums (in mysql) for that values (I feel thats good option but i have read some articles saying to avoid)
3. I should create lookup tables for these options and use foreign key constraint in parent table.

If i trade off between these choice what i get is:

- In Opt 1 i get database size, and peformance issues due to string scanning for query and experts may not consider it as a good design
- In Opt 2 i didn't feel any performance issue but most of people saying if i have to add new value i may have issues
- In Opt 3 i don't want to use joins as there may be more then 30 to 40 lookup tables to display complete record and if i don't use join join so i may need to create array to lookup values against 1,2,3,4 options or i have to use if or switch statements,
  as my project would be scaleable and can contain records arround 1 million to 2 million.

I would really thank full to you experts if you help me out.

Note: i also want to ask expert is having a lookup array against database lookup tabe good practice ? as someone asked me to do so and use enumerators.

Comment: Option 4: Store as integer and resolve to enum in your DB access class

Comment: I am using laravel (Eloquent) orm. so you are saying, i should resolve this integer value in my model class,

Comment: Exactly. e.g. status: 1 = open, 2 = closed will be stored as 1, 2 in DB, and resolved to "open", "closed" in your class. e.g. you can define the status as constant that equals the integer for easy mapping.

Comment: Got it, but what i am trying to achieve is to keep database integrity and consistency using foreign key or enum. and in my case lookup table numbers can be more then 40 to 50 so i was looking for enum.

Comment: This looks helpful for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362044/mysql-enum-type-vs-join-tables